# WPF RadioButton Click with RaiseEvent

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button, routed-events

We have a simple control that inherits from a RadioButton.  I would like to programmically check it.

If it were a button we would click we would normally do.

```
Button MyButton = ...
MyButtonClickArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent, MyButton);
MyButton.RaiseEvent(MyButtonClickArgs);
```

So I figured I could do the following with a RadioButton.

```
RadioButton MyButton = ...
MyButtonClickArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(RadioButton.CheckedEvent, MyButton);
MyButton.RaiseEvent(MyButtonClickArgs);
```

No such luck however.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong.

**Update:**
Upon further exploration is does appear the OnChecked event handler is being called.  However the IsChecked state is false (so it does not do what I expected it to).  If IsChecked is false I would expect it to be true by the time the event handler is called.  At least that is the behavior if I physically click the button.

Comment: It should work. What is going wrong? Aren't you receiving the event? Can you show your event handler code?

Comment: @PraveenPaulose The event handler does get called, just not in the state I am expecting.  See updated question.

Answer (score 2):

In your example you are only firing an event. Firing off the event does not automatically set the value of the Radio Button to IsChecked: true. Your example for Button Click is fine, but in the case of a Radio Button, you do not need to fire the event explicitly. You can directly set the property IsChecked = true

```
radioButton.IsChecked = true;
```

This will check the radio button and trigger your event calling your Checked event handler.

When you physically check the button, under the hoods it would set the property IsChecked and not just trigger the event.

Adding the relevant sections of the Radio Button Source code from WPF

```
/// <summary>
/// This override method is called from OnClick().
/// RadioButton implements its own toggle behavior 
/// </summary>
protected internal override void OnToggle() 
{ 
    IsChecked = true;
}
```

[Radion Button Source Code](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/WIN_WINDOWS/lh_tools_devdiv_wpf/Windows/wcp/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/RadioButton@cs/1/RadioButton@cs)

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for.  I'm not looking to manually change the check state, I'm looking to simulate a user doing so.  This is in some test code. Subtle difference.

Comment: @denver Just explaining the designed framework behavior and suggesting an alternative

Comment: @denver Added relvant source from WPF showing how it is managed from within the control source code.